# How to filter HTML select tags in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-filter, django-filters

i am trying to use [How to use Q objects to filter complex queries](https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-orm-cookbook/en/latest/query_relatedtool.html), it works with search type input but not with select tag. when I try to filter a set of an input and two selects it returns an empty QuerySet. image below:

[Debugger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwNsF.png)

I have no idea why this happens. There is another way to filter sets of HTML tags?

My model

```
tfrom django.db import models
from categories.models import Category

from choices.stt_choices import STATE_CHOICES
from choices.occupation_choices import OCCUPATION_AREA_CHOICES


class Vacancy(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=255)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    contact_number = models.PositiveBigIntegerField('Phone number')
    contact_whatsapp = models.PositiveBigIntegerField('WhatsApp')
    contact_email = models.EmailField('E-mail')
    occupation_area = models.CharField(
        'Occupation area',
        max_length=3,
        choices=OCCUPATION_AREA_CHOICES
        )
    state = models.CharField('State', max_length=2, choices=STATE_CHOICES)
    city = models.CharField('City', max_length=255)
    number = models.IntegerField('Vacancies number', default=0)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    img = models.ImageField(
        'Image', upload_to='vacancies_img/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True, null=True
        )
    salary = models.CharField('Salary', max_length=255)
    about_company = models.TextField('About the company')
    requirements = models.TextField('Requirements')
    activities = models.TextField('Activities')
    benefits = models.TextField('Benefits', blank=True, null=True)
    schedule =  models.TextField('Schedule')
    

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name
```

My view

```
from vacancies.models import Vacancy
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.db.models import Q


class VacancyHome(ListView):
    model = Vacancy
    template_name = 'vacancies/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'vacancies'


class VacancySearch(VacancyHome):
    template_name = 'vacancies/search.html'
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Vacancy.objects.all()

        search = self.request.GET.get('search')
        occupation = self.request.GET.get('occupation')
        state = self.request.GET.get('state')

        if search and occupation and state:
            qsos = qs.filter(
                Q(occupation_area__icontains=occupation) &
                Q(name__icontains=search) &
                Q(state__icontains=state) 
            )
            return qsos
        
        return qs
```

My django template form

```
<form action="{% url 'vacancies:vacancy_search' %}" method="get">
    <input type="search" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Profession, Job Role, etc...">
    <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01" name="occupation">
        <option selected disabled>Occupation</option>
        {% for occupation in vacancies %}
            <option>{{ occupation.get_occupation_area_display }}</option>      
        {% endfor %}
      </select>

      <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01" name="state">
        <option selected disabled>State</option>
        {% for state in vacancies %}
            <option>{{ state.get_state_display }}</option>      
        {% endfor %}
      </select>

    <button type="submit" value="{{ request.GET.search }}" class="btn btn-dark"> 
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-search"
        viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M11.742 10.344a6.5 6.5 0 1 0-1.397 1.398h-.001c.03.04.062.078.098.115l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 0 0 
        1.415-1.414l-3.85-3.85a1.007 1.007 0 0 0-.115-.1zM12 6.5a5.5 5.5 0 1 1-11 0 5.5 5.5 0 0 1 11 0z"/>
        </svg>
    </button>

</form>
```